# Select Between Strings - PHP

Tags: php, arrays, string, preg-replace, strstr

I have text like:

`$tagPossible  = '365 Wallpapers now available on Nokia Store for #NokiaX family @nokiadeveloper @nokia';`

There are two words in this string with @nokiadeveloper and @nokia

What i have been done is that this two strings ( which can be X ) i want to store into my database.

> $tag = strstr($tagPossible, '@'); 
>  echo $converTag =
>   str_replace('@', '', $tag);

This is my Output:
**nokiadeveloper nokia**

Becouse there are two tags, i want to import them as two rows into my database.
So i need to be specific when import this strings.

How i'm able to select this strings?
I want to select only nokiadeveloper and nokia as array.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`preg_match_all()`](http://php.net/preg_match_all) with a positive lookahead to extract all the required strings:

```
(?<=\s)@(\w+)
```

Explanation:

- `(?<=\s)` - if preceded by a whitespace character
- `@` - match literal `@` character
- `(\w+)` - match (and capture) any word character `[A-Za-z0-9_]`

Code:

```
$ok = preg_match_all('/(?<=\s)@(\w+)/', $tagPossible, $matches);

if ($ok) {
    $arr = $matches[1];
}

print_r($arr);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => nokiadeveloper
    [1] => nokia
)
```

Comment: Awesome, i have been selected the answer. It's working nice. THX for your solution.

Answer (score 0):

In addition, [here's another solution](https://eval.in/108444) that maybe helpful. Just because I hate Regex:

```
$tag = strstr($tagPossible, '@');    
$tags = explode('@', $tag);

foreach($tags as $tag) {
    echo trim($tag). PHP_EOL;
}
```